# improving image quality from AREA GOES imager data using WCT or other program?

Tags: meteorology

I'm doing a project using two days worth of GOES 13 satellite data during June, 2016.  I'm trying to make an HD animation using data from bands 1 and 4.  I've been using the Weather & Climate Toolkit that NOAA provides, but I am finding inferior quality uncompressed AVI output.  It doesn't matter what background I'm using, but it seems as if the image data has it's lowest and highest histogram points clipped.  I've tried as many settings as I can use in the WCT program, but nothing changes.  However, if I were to make an AVI using GIF format, the result is much better, but this will take a lot longer since I'll have to import the GIF's into a different program and assemble each frame into an AVI.  Since using WCT is easier, my question is: how do I improve the AVI result and if it can't be done with WCT, are there other free programs I could try that would do the same thing with the AREA data (produce a quality AVI)?  Thank you.